# How to use '--acl bucket-owner-full-control' in npx s3p cp command

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, npx

Need to copy objects from one bucket to another account, using 'npx s3p cp'. It works recursively by default.
How to use '--acl bucket-owner-full-control' in the command or similar since I need to set  destination bucket owner as newly copied objects owner.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The tool doesn't appear to have a way to set ACLs when copying. You might want to seek advice via an issue at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/generalui/s3p).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. . alternative option works only if we could do '--acl bucket-owner-full-control'' in the command.

Comment: It seems that you are correct. The new S3 Object Ownership feature doesn't allow you, the bucket owner, to unilaterally dictate that you take ownership; the uploading client has to permit the ownership. That's disappointing, but I suppose understandable to prevent problems when accidentally uploading to someone else's bucket. I'll update my answer shortly.